# Regexp para validar URLs compartidas

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy haciendo un Regexp que valida que la cadena sea un recurso compartido por ejemplo `\\192.168.1.1\MiCarpeta\Mi subcarpeta`
He tomado del foro inglés la parte de la IP

```
/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/
```

He hecho varios experimentos pero no consigo el resultado intenté esto

```
/[\\.]\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b[/.][a-zA-Z\-0-9\/]/
```

`[\\.]` Como parte del inicio de la cadena
`[\.]` Una invertida despues de la IP
`[a-zA-Z\-0-9\]` Y alfanumericos con "\" incluidas

Me estoy iniciando en expresiones regulares, me gustaría conocerlas a fondo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar con esta expresión regular:

```
\\\\(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(\\[a-zA-Z\-0-9 \/])+
```

gráficamente lo puedes apreciar así:

[image: diagrama de ferrocarril de la máquina de estados del regex]

Como puedes observar la diagonal invertida la puse con `\\` y en el último grupo puse que se pudiera repetir para que te aceptara la ruta de tus carpetas y le incluí los espacios en blanco.

Comment: El flujograma está padre, cual usas?

Comment: Si resolvió tu problema dale click en el botón de la palomita. Como eres la segunda persona que lo pregunta en SOes te paso el artículo que hice acerca de [herramientas para trabajar con regex](http://javapro.org/castellano/2018/03/04/herramientas-para-expresiones-regulares/)

Comment: Le faltó una \b antes de iniciar con la validación de IP, pero de ahí en fuera, excelente. Gracias por la herramienta